# Probability question, 6 A people, 14 B people, choose 3 for activity A, 2 activity B, 6 for activity C, what is the number of ways total?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

An upcoming super bowl party includes 6 New York Giants fans and 14 Patriots fans. The host will randomly assign guests (choosing names out of a hat) to bring food as follows: 3 to bring wings, 2 to bring cookies, and 6 to bring chips. Once the 11 food assignments have been made, the others will not be asked to bring anything. If no guest is assigned to bring more than one thing, in how many different ways can the host randomly choose which guests perform these tasks?

(From comment): I'm not sure but I think you use combination. Is it either 20C3 *20C2 * 20C6 or 14C3*14C2*14C6+6C3*6C2*6C6? I know how to do the question if it was just one group to select out of, but with 2 groups I don't know how to combine them.

Bonus: Return the the previous question. Suppose that Giants fans do not fancy Pepsi. If the host hands a Pepsi to 14 random people at the party, what is the probability that they are all Patriots fans?

For the bonus, I think the answer is (20! 6!)/14!

Any suggestions on how I should approach this problem?

Comment: what are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you use combination. Is it either 20C3 *20C2 * 20C6  or 14C3*14C2*14C6+6C3*6C2*6C6? I don't think the second answer is right though. Edit: I know how to do the question if it was just one group to select out of, but with 2 groups I don't know how to combine them. What are your thoughts? Can you help me?

Comment: For the first part: You can probably ignore which teams people support, as you are looking for individual guests.  But your initial suggested answer is too high: once you have selected $3$ out of $20$ to bring wings, that only leaves a possible $17$ to choose from for  the cookies and chips.

Comment: For the second part: your answer is greater than $1$ and so cannot be a probability

Comment: Oh, I understand this problem now. Treat them as one group of 20 people, the. Use combination. 20C3 * 17C2 * 15C6